# More pythonic way to go over list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got two list of lists. I'm about iterating though them and looking for common elements at the same positions.

If any element in list of 
elements_to_check list matches and is not in unique_list I add it there.

If none of elements match I want to append this list into not_match_list.

Below you have my code example. It almost works. I don't know why in the end in not_match_list I've got [2, 3, 'd'] (eg. [2, 3, 'c'] or [2, 4 'd'] are already in unique_list)
Could anyone explain me why there's [2, 3, 'd'] in not_match_list and/or suggest me how to rewrite this code more pythonic, please?

```
unique_list = [[1, 2, 'a'], [4, 2, 'b'], [1, 3, 'c'], [2, 3, 'c'], [2, 4, 'd']]
not_match_list = []
elements_to_check = [[2, 3, 'a'], [3, 4, 'a'], [4, 2, 'a'], [4, 2, 'a'], [2, 3, 'd'], [9, 9, 'z']]

print(unique_list)
for unique_element in unique_list:
    for element_to_check in elements_to_check:
        if element_to_check[0] == unique_element[0] and element_to_check not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(element_to_check)
        elif element_to_check[1] == unique_element[1] and element_to_check not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(element_to_check)
        elif element_to_check[2] == unique_element[2] and element_to_check not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(element_to_check)
        elif element_to_check not in unique_list and element_to_check not in not_match_list:
            not_match_list.append(element_to_check)

print(unique_list)
print(not_match_list)
```

expected result:

```
unique_list =  [[1, 2, 'a'], [4, 2, 'b'], [1, 3, 'c'], [2, 3, 'c'], [2, 4, 'd'], [2, 3, 'a'], [3, 4, 'a'], [4, 2, 'a'], [2, 3, 'd']]
not_match_list =  [[9, 9, 'z']]
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to do. You have two lists, and what do you want in the third list?

Comment: unique_list - it's a final list \n\n
elements_to_check - list of elements which need to be checked. If any element is common with elements in unique_list AND such list is not in unique_elements, you need to append unique_list by that element. \n\n
not_match_list - list for lists from elements_to_check which have not any common elements with elements in unique list

Comment: So what should the answer be to this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can achieve what you want with just a slight rearrangement of your code:

```
for element_to_check in elements_to_check:
    for unique_element in unique_list:
        if element_to_check[0] == unique_element[0] and element_to_check not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(element_to_check)
        elif element_to_check[1] == unique_element[1] and element_to_check not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(element_to_check)
        elif element_to_check[2] == unique_element[2] and element_to_check not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(element_to_check)

    if element_to_check not in unique_list and element_to_check not in not_match_list:
        not_match_list.append(element_to_check)
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full solution, but if I understand you correctly, you can at least simplify this:

```
if element_to_check[0] == unique_element[0] and element_to_check not in unique_list:
    unique_list.append(element_to_check)
elif element_to_check[1] == unique_element[1] and element_to_check not in unique_list:
    unique_list.append(element_to_check)
elif element_to_check[2] == unique_element[2] and element_to_check not in unique_list:
    unique_list.append(element_to_check)
elif element_to_check not in unique_list and element_to_check not in not_match_list:
    not_match_list.append(element_to_check)
```

to this:

```
if any(to_check == unique for to_check, unique in zip(element_to_check, unique_list)) and element_to_check not in unique_list:
    unique_list.append(element_to_check)
else:
    not_match_list.append(element_to_check)
```